# Comparing object in array to everything else in same array

Tags: java, arrays, compare

I want to compare each item in an array to every other item in said array. I'm doing this at the moment, is it ok or is there a prettier/faster/more logical way of doing it?

```
for(int i=0; i<array1.size(); i++){
  for(int j=0; j<array1.size(); j++){
    if(i!=j){
      ..do stuff..
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're doing too many comparisons, plus you're comparing every item to itself needlessly. What you want is this:

```
for(int i=0; i<array1.size(); i++){
  for(int j=i + 1; j<array1.size(); j++){
     if(arr[i] != arr[j]){
        ..do stuff..
     }
  }
}
```

(This is assuming that your idea of equality is [commutative](http://www.mathsisfun.com/associative-commutative-distributive.html), which equality normally is.)

If there are N items in your array, your original snippet would be doing N^2 comparisons, whereas my snippet is doing N(N-1)/2 comparisons.

Comment: The "if(i!=j){" condition is unnecessary. j is always > i.

Comment: He's not literally comparing i to j, he means comparing those objects in the array. Have clarified my pseudo code to show that.

Answer (score 4):

Provided your comparison-relation is [**symmetrical**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation) you could do away with

```
for(int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++) {

    // Note the initial value of j
    for(int j = i + 1; j < array1.size(); j++) {
        if (i != j) {
            ..do stuff..
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative style (which keeps indentation down) is to do

```
for(int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++) {

    // Note the initial value of j
    for(int j = i + 1; j < array1.size(); j++) {
        if (i == j)
            continue;

        ..do stuff..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as speed goes you could just loop until `j < i` instead of the whole array in the inner clause and that should cover you.

eg if array is = [1,2,3,4] you'd get

- For 1: Don't compare.
- For 2: Compare to 1.
- For 3: Compare to 1 2.
- For 4: Compare to 1 2 3.

So all are compared.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why that wouldn't work.

Although I always thought that you had to call .length on arrays (as it's a field and not a method).